# Class inaccessible pointer

Tags: c++

Hello need your help to solve this problem or just explain me why my pointer is inaccessible .

PlayerSprite.h

```
#pragma once
#include "LoadPlayerRes.h"
#include "Keyboard.h"
#include "PlayerState.h"

class PlayerSprite :public LoadPlayerRes{
public:
    PlayerSprite(float x, float y,float speed)
        :
        x(x),
        y(y),
        speed(speed)
    {
        pCurrentState = new StateStand(&Stand);
    }
    void Controls(Keyboard& kbd) {
        speed = 0;
        if (speed == 0) {
            delete pCurrentState;
            pCurrentState = new StateStand(&Stand);
        }
    }
    void Draw(Graphics& gfx) {
        pCurrentState->pSprite->Draw(x, y, gfx);// pSprite inaccessible 
    }
private:
    float x, y,speed;
    PlayerState* pCurrentState;
};
```

PlayerState.h

```
#pragma once
#include "SurfaceAnimation.h"
class PlayerState {
public:
    PlayerState(SurfaceAnimation* pSprite)
        :
        pSprite(pSprite)
    {}
protected:
    SurfaceAnimation* pSprite;
};

class StateStand :public PlayerState {
public:
    StateStand(SurfaceAnimation* pSprite)
        :
        PlayerState(pSprite)
    {}
};
```

so i am trying to make a player state machine ,PlayerState class job is to point to right SurfaceAnimation object and based on pointer i will draw a player inside PlayerSprite class , but for some reason pSprite is inaccessible.

Comment: `pSprite` is `protected`, why would you expect it's accessible from an unrelated class?

Comment: It would help readability and potentially avoid problems if you named your function parameter differently to your class member (e.g. `pSprite(pSprite)`)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Because pCurrentState is a pointer of a PlayerState so i think it should be able to access it do i am wrong ?

Comment: @yahoo5000 yes, that is wrong.

Comment: @Component10: Meh, looks fine to me.

Comment: @yahoo5000 It is able to access it, but it isn't accessing it - `*this` is. `pCurrentState->pSprite` doesn't mean "ask pCurrentState to do something with its pSprite", but "give me the pSprite from pCurrentState". And a `PlayerSprite` isn't allowed to touch that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you don't think it's a little confusing that two variables have the same name?

Comment: @Component10: In this scenario, no not really.

Comment: @Component10 i am using a Visual Studio 2015 witch makes parameters grey , its easy to track , in some other cases i would do them same

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I take your point, though I would still have named them differently, denoting the class member to avoid confusion with local variables. Just an observation.

Comment: @Component10: If I were to rename anything it would be the constructor parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It's inaccessible because you made it `protected`.**

So, only functions in `PlayerState` (or functions in classes inheriting `PlayerState`), can see it.

You're trying to access it from a function in `PlayerSprite`.

Comment: I know pSprite is protected but pCurrentState should be able to access it ?because pCurrentState is a PlayerState*

Comment: @yahoo5000: `pCurrentState` can access it (i.e. from within its _own_ functions), but that's not what you wrote.

Comment: So i guess to solve this i would have to make it public or will make a public function to access it ?

Comment: @yahoo5000: That's right. Or make `PlayerSprite` a `friend`.

Comment: @yahoo5000 Or add a public `Draw` function to the state.

Comment: Right. Which is kind of weird potentially but meh

Comment: I was thinking about Draw inside state but then change my mind cuz i think its PlayerSprite job to do so

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `PlayerSprites` are never `friendly`.